# Java URLConnection utf-8 encoding doesn't work

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, urlconnection

I'm writing a small crawler for sites in English only, and doing that by opening a `URL` connection. I set the encoding to `utf-8` both on the request, and the `InputStreamReader` but I continue to get gobbledigook for some of the requests, while others work fine.

The following code represents all the research I did and advice out there. I have also tried changing `URLConnection` to `HttpURLConnection` with no luck. Some of the returned strings continue to look like this:

??}?r?H????P?n?c??]?d?G?o??Xj{?x?"P$a?Qt?#&??e?a#?????lfVx)?='b?"Y(defUeefee=??????.??a8??{O??????zY?2?M???3c??@

What am I missing?

My code:

```
public static String getDocumentFromUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    String wholeDocument = null;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60*1000); // wait only 60 seconds for a response
        conn.setReadTimeout(60*1000);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            wholeDocument += inputLine;     
        }       
        isr.close();
        in.close();         

    return wholeDocument;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample URL that fails? Have you looked at what's coming across the network (e.g. with Wireshark)?

Comment: That doesn't look like text at all.  Is it (perhaps) a PDF file?  Or compressed?  I doubt that this is a "simple" problem with UTF-8.

Comment: Here's a URL that fails. Again, it only fails sometimes. At others it works fine. http://www.broadbandtvnews.com/2014/02/04/samsung-adds-the-weather-channel/

Comment: I would have thought u need to look at the http response headers to find out what the content type is and character set used. I haven't looked at the docs about setting http request property but I think it is just a hint for the other party. They may not follow your hint.

Comment: Just had a look. I think you should be calling getContentType, getContentEncoding() and getContentLength() to get some idea what content you are dealing with so you can properly handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server is sending the document GZIP compressed. You can set the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header to make it send the document in plain text.

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
```

Even so, the HTTP client class handles GZIP compression for you, so you shouldn't have to worry about details like this. What seems to be going on here is that the server is buggy: it does not send the `Content-Encoding` header to tell you the content is compressed. This behavior seems to depend on the `User-Agent`, so that the site works in regular web browsers but breaks when used from Java. So, setting the user agent also fixes the issue:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"); // for example
```